# Ocramius / Doctrine & Zend validate-schema Acess denied

Tags: zend-framework, console, doctrine, autoload, git-bash

I am doing the tutorial from Marco Pivetta for Ocramius and Zend, I am stuck at the step where I should validate the schema. (See here: [Link to the tutorial](http://marco-pivetta.com/doctrine-orm-zf2-tutorial/#/24) )
So actually I am stuck at the same point like at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22661880/doctrine-validate-schema-pdoexception), already asked on stackoverflow.
The author on this question found the solution obviously, but for me it's not working. 
He writes

> And, if you use gitBash don't forget if you have tested your APPLICATION_ENV variable in application.config.php like this tutorial Zf2 advances config setup do in bash_profile file.
>
> > export APPLICATION_ENV="development"

I did this in my application.config.php

```
$env = getenv('APP_ENV') ?: 'development';

// Use the $env value to determine which modules to load
$modules = array(
        'ZendDeveloperTools',
        'Application',
        'DoctrineModule',
        'DoctrineORMModule',
);
if ($env == 'production') {
    $modules[] = 'ZendDeveloperTools';
}

return array(
    'modules' => $modules,
[...]
```

But I still get the error

> [PDOException]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I have to say though, I couldn't figure out what the author means with the

> [... ] bash_profile file:
>
> export APPLICATION_ENV="development

His sentence is written without regarding any grammatical sense.

So the problem is:
Somehow my doctrine.local.php in the autoloads is ignored, I can't figure out why.

I am using GitBash for the 
    ./vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:validate-schema
command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it:
Make sure you are using GitBash and ZendStudio in administrator mode -.-